# Why am I getting a syntax error on this code from the tensorflow website?

Tags: python, tensorflow, syntax-error

I am learning tensorflow using the tensorflow website, and I directly copied the code from their website to test for myself. However, for some reason, I am unable to run the code, due to a syntax error. What is wrong with this if I hadn't tweaked any of this code?

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
    # Two hidden layers of 30 and 10 nodes respectively.
    hidden_units=[30, 10],
    # The model must choose between 3 classes.
    n_classes=3

classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train, train_y, training=True),
    steps=5000)

classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(test, test_y, training=False))
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Don't use pictures, instead copy and paste the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have forgotten to close the parenthesis at line 45:

```
    n_classes=3
)  # <-- this one
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a closing parenthesis after `n_classes=3` on line 45.